# What is the regular expression for space and alpha-numeric

Tags: php

I'm using ajax check function to check inserted category name which should be only alpha-numeric and also allowed space

I've used this function `eregi_replace` with the following regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

```
$check = eregi_replace('([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', "", $catname);
```

But when i insert category name for example `hello world` it failed cause it does not accept space but if i write it as `helloworld` works so i understood that the error must be in the regular expression i'm using.

so what is the correct regular expression that filter any special characters and allow only for alpha-numeric and space.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

A character class matching letters, numbers, the underscore and space would be

```
[\w ]
```

You should *not* be using any of the POSIX regular expression functions as they are now deprecated. Instead, use their superior counterparts from the [PCRE suite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Answer (score 3):

Change your regular expression to:

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+(?: +[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*)
```

I realize that it is not as straightforward as you might have hoped.  Things to note:

- The identifier must start with a non-space
- If there are spaces, they should be between words and not matched at the end
- `?:` is used to prevent an extra grouping in your expression, but is not required
- The `+` after the space character allows multiple spaces between words.  You can enforce a single space by removing it, but in some solutions, it is a better practice to normalize the space internally with a `preg_split` that matches on `" +"` (a space with a plus sign) and then use `implode(" ", $array)`.  But eh... if you are just validating, this should be fine.

Comment: +1 Whilst this answer makes a lot of assumptions, I'd say you've nailed it. FYI, you can shrink `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to `\w`

Answer (score 2):

you've got it nearly right, just add \s into your square brackets and "hello world" will pass.

([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+)

Comment: That will match any whitespace character including tab, carriage return and line feed

Answer (score 1):

I've got some help by old friend and i've tested and works perfect - thank you all for answers and comments it was very helpful to me.

this works perfect

```
$check = eregi_replace('(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$)', "", $catname);
```

Alphanumeric and white space regular expression

@Phil
yours works perfect but still will pass underscore ~ thanks

@Michael Hays
I do not know it didn't worked for whitespace , but your comments is very helpful ~ thanks

@kjetilh
I will read more about $preg ~ thanks

@Alastair
Works fine if i've replaced \s with just whitespace !  ~ thanks

Comment: I assumed from the code in your question that you actually wanted the underscore. Also, why are you ignoring the advice regarding `eregi_replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

[eregi functions are deprecated as of php 5.3. Use preg instead.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php)

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer his question in the slightest

Comment: While you're right good practices and security notices are often submitted as answers

Comment: @kjetilh Yes, and then they are flagged and moved to a comment by a moderator